# Data points are empty on AWS response

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have a function that gets the stats for an instance. It passes through the rigth details. But unfortunately I am just getting empty data points. Any ideas?

```
public Object getMetricStatisticResults(Credentials creds, Amazon.RegionEndpoint region, string instanceID, int period, string[] statistics, DateTime starttime, DateTime endtime )
        {
            var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudWatchClient(creds, region);
            var dimension = new Dimension
            {
                Name = "InstanceID",
                Value = instanceID
            };

            var request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest();
            request.Dimensions.Add(dimension);


            var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            request.StartTime = starttime; //checked and it is all correct! -5 days
            request.EndTime = endtime; //checked, showing now value!

            request.Namespace = "AWS/EC2"; //not sure what this is but added in as per examples

            request.MetricName = "CPUUtilization"; //what I want to get
            request.Statistics.Add("Average"); //I want others but reducing to minimum so that I can test the easier part.
            request.Period = 300;
            var response = client.GetMetricStatistics(request);

            if(response.Datapoints.Count > 0)
            {
               //never happens
            }
            else
            {
               //always happens!!! grrrrr
            }
        }
```

I have tried changing the region zones as well (I did some googling) but that did not solve my problem, and I can confirm that the one chosen is correct anyway.

Is there something in the main AWS console that needs to be enable for this to happen? Am I missing something? Spent a long time testing different things so far but nothing really worked. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the following line of code:

```
{
                Name = "InstanceID",
                Value = instanceID
            };
```

It should say "InstanceId", note the small 'd' at the end. This solved it for me.
Solution:

```
  {
                    Name = "InstanceId",
                    Value = instanceID
                };
```